# How can I use an if-else condition inside a list comprehension to overwrite an existing list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, in-place

I'm trying to multiply numbers greater than 3 by two, and subtract one from everything else. However, nothing happens to the list.
This is my code:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print (lst)

[x*2 if x > 3 else x-1 for x in lst]     

print (lst)
```

Why aren't the contents of the *lst* variable modified by the list comprehension?

Comment: `[x*2 if x > 3 else x-1 for x in lst]` is just an expression, it will return a value but you haven't assign this value to a variable yet.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt re-assigned it to the variable name.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print (lst)

lst = [x*2 if x > 3 else x-1 for x in lst]

print (lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

### List Comprehensions and Assignment

You're missing an assignment. [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like yours don't do in-place modifications to the list elements. Instead, the expression returns a new list, so you must *assign* the result of the list comprehension expression back to a variable. For example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list = [x*2 if x > 3 else x-1 for x in list]
print(list)
```

In Ruby, there are certainly methods for performing self-mutating operations, but I'm not personally aware of a Python equivalent that retains the semantics that you're trying to use here.

Comment: @Rakitić Please don't make trivial edits to other people's answers, especially when you aren't clear on the subtle differences in connotation between specific word choices. If you have questions about what constitutes a non-trivial edit, please ask a related question on meta.